# C# Using ProcessStartInfo and Process.HasExited

Tags: c#, process, processstartinfo

I want to use `ProcessStartInfo` to startup programs from my C# application. I am using `ProcessStartInfo` insted of normal `Process` because I want to startup programs minimized so I will be using `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized` and maybe I will also pass some arguments. I also want to monitor those started applications after so I want to use for example `Process.HasExited` property (and also `PeakWorkingSet64`) but I can't as I got an error `'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' does not contain a definition for 'HasExited'`. Is there any way to start applications with `ProcessStartInfo` and also using properties that are available with standard `Process` class?

Comment: *A code is worth a thousand words*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessStartInfo` is a class that defines settings that you want to pass into an overload of `Process.Start`.

So, you would typically do something like this:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo { ... };
var process = Process.Start("C:\myProgram.exe", psi);
process.Exited += myProcessExitHandler;
```

Answer (score 2):

`ProcessStartInfo` is just a structure that describes how to start a process.  Once you define it, you pass it to `Process.Start()` and get back instance of `Process`.  On that instance you can call `.HasExited`.